# Random 503 and 504 errors

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors

Recently I have been getting a lot of 503 errors. They don't happen in any pattern. The only way to get them to willingly show up is by opening a bunch of orders(20-50) in WooCommerce. But sometimes it just seems to happen very randomly.

**I have tried:**

- Create a test domain
- Update PHP version
- Disabled a lot of plugins
- Update plugins/wordpress etc
- even tried caching
- Reading the debug file and logs in the root (nothing of use)

But nothing seems to get rid of the random 503 errors. The issue is very annoying when working on our orders but also shows for our customers. Google doesn't have any answer and I simply don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you monitor CPU and memory use when this is happening - are one or both of them overloaded? Is this a single VM hosting both MySQL and WordPress, or are they separate?

Comment: According to the logs the CPU and memory never really pass the limit. CPU takes like 5-10% max. Memory 20% max. Entry Processes reach 50% at max. Nothing spectacular if you ask me. I think our server hosts both MySQL and WordPress but I am not sure.

Comment: Agree with Rup, could be a resource issue on the server whe it's under load. More info on how the server is setup may help diagnose (e.g. is it a VPS, how much memory, what is your PHP memory setting? Command line tool 'ab' is useful for firing a whole bunch of requests that allow you to quickly saturate your server to replicate the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's a VPS. I think it's a Linux based server, 8 gigs of ram, 12 cores cpu. PHP allows for 2000m and I think that's the maximum I'm allowed to pick. Running php 7.3.

Comment: Anything in logs? Nginx or Apache?